# Spring @Autowired confusing

Tags: java, spring

I think I found a confusing problem.
I have two classes under the package 'cao'
One is:

```
@Repository
public class MovieFinder {
}
```

The other is:

```
public class SimpleMovieLister {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    private MovieFinder movieFinder;

    public MovieFinder getMovieFinder() {
        return movieFinder;
    }

    public void setMovieFinder(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
        this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
    }
}
```

In the application xml file,I define as follows

```
<bean class="cao.SimpleMovieLister"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="cao"/>
<bean id="1" class="cao.MovieFinder"/>
```

Then the program can run normally.
But what confused me is that now we have two instances of type MovieFinder.Why not throw a exception?

After I change the @Repository to @Repository(value="2"),the expected exception is thrown.
WOW,please help me.
thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean "we have two instances of type MovieFinder"? And what exception are you expecting to be thrown?

Comment: What I mean is that now we have two instances from the IoC.One is the instance instantiated explicitly via <bean id="1" class="cao.MovieFinder"/>.And the other is created by the component-scan mechanism.</br>When confronted with @Autowired,should not it throw an exception for having more than 1 candidate?

Comment: What makes you think you have two instances from the IoC? @Autowired doesn't create an object if it doesn't need to.

Comment: One is created explicitly and the other is created implicitly via the component-scan mechanism.

Comment: No, component-scan is not so stupid as to create a second object and then throw an exception because there are two candidates.  In general Spring resolves object references to a single object unless you specify that you want multiple objects and does not create a new object when one that satisfies the requirements already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on [spring documentation:](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

> By default, the autowiring fails whenever zero candidate beans are available

It doesn't really care if there's more than 1 candidates, because in fact you can autowire multiple candidates into an array / collection.

It seems whenever you have multiple candidates, it will autowire the last created beans -- but I cannot find anything on the documentation that supports this. Never rely on this behavior.

So far I haven't yet found a way to configure autowiring to fail if there's more than 1 candidate -- I guess you have to create your own [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) and/or override [AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html)

I'd say best practice is to avoid having multiple candidates, either by providing extra qualifier, or avoid creating unecessary candidates.

Comment: Thanks first for your long comment.But what I want to say is that there will be an error if I confiure more than 1 candidate and it is what is happening to me.

Answer (score 0):

> But what confused me is that now we have two instances of type
>   MovieFinder.

If you are using [annotation based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) (`@Repository`) then why you are configuring this bean second time `<bean id="1" class="cao.MovieFinder"/>` in XML? This is why you have two identical beans.

Comment: I am studying and practicing.So maybe the code and configuration are very ugly.Please forgive me.